# "overlay_*" functions not working in PyQGIS with getFeatures() expression

Tags: pyqgis, features, expression, overlapping-features, filter

I am trying to use `overlay_intersects()` inside an expression in order to loop through the features from a target layer that intersect with a feature having a certain `"id"`.

```py
request_string = "overlay_intersects(layer:='"+target_layer_name+"', filter:=id='"+matching_feature_id+"')"
features = current_layer.getFeatures(request_string)

for feat in features:
    print(feat.attribute('name')+" intersects with the feature having id '"+matching_feature_id+"'")
```

But this doesn't loop, all features are evaluated to false in this situation.

If I use the same expression in the Field Calculator and set a field like `matches` with it, this is going to work as expected: all features from the current layer that intersect with the one having id `matching_feature_id` in the target layer will have their field `matches` set to `true` and the others to `false`.

Field `matches` (boolean) = `overlay_intersects(layer:='target_layer_name', filter:=id='matching_feature_id')`

- QGIS: 3.22.7-Białowieża
- Python: 3.9.2

Comment: What are those variables `target_layer_name` and `matching_feature_id` in your expression? If they are variables you have defined previously in the Python code, then you need to insert them into the expression properly e.g. with f-string formatting, otherwise they will be interpreted as string literals. The same goes for how you are using it in your print statement.

Comment: It's for the sake of clarity on StackEchange, they are indeed variables that end up being concatenated. But I also tried not using it as a variable and put the actual ids in the string to see if it works.

I edited my question so it doesn't add unnecessary confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was caused because the two layers were using two different projections (e.i. EPSG4326 and EPSG2154). I reprojected the first one to EPSG2154 and it worked!

However I'd be happy to get some hints from the community about why PyQGIS couldn't do it whereas the Field Calculator had no problem to deal with it. I was induced in error because the panel showed points correctly placed upon each other.

Answer (score 2):

You must to build [`QgsFeatureRequest()`](https://docs.qgis.orglatest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#filtering-a-layer-with-expressions) object with your expression.

Try this:

```py
request_string = "overlay_intersects(layer:='target_layer_name', filter:=id='matching_feature_id')"
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(request_string)
features = current_layer.getFeatures(request)

for feat in features:
    print(feat.attribute('name')+' intersects with the feature having id "matching_feature_id"')
```

Take a look to the [Filtering a layer with expressions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#filtering-a-layer-with-expressions) documentation.

Comment: I test it and it worked fine. Verify that you are using the id of the layer not the name, an id looks like this: ```New_scratch_layer_436261ed_c8d0_47f2_8e0a_9c44c7079f65```.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it too but it didn't work, I just tried again with your code without success.

It shouldn't be necessary to use this intermediate class according to the documentation https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures

To me it seems like overlay_intersects() function doesn't behave the same in this context compared to the Field Calculator.

Comment: I did that too, seems to be a bug 

Comment: And the query thing works fine as I can get all the features by replacing the current expression by `true` to match all features.

Comment: Try without the filter first to debug the expression: ```overlay_intersects(layer:='target_layer_name')```

Comment: Did that too, nothing gets returned, sorry. I spent a couple of hours to get it working, it just doesn't make sense really.